# How can I accept credit card payment without leaving my website?

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment

I'm creating an eCommerce website and I was researching on how I can accept credit cards on my website. I came across a lot of payment gateways but they do the processing on their website and I don't want my visitors to leave my URL. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want visitors to leave your URL?

Comment: This is a security threat for your visitors, to pass any credit card data to your site. Why do you want it?

Comment: @RB. This is because I want the design to stay the same to my checkout page.

Comment: This is a security threat. It is not about design.

Comment: It's usually safer and better to use third party payment processor. Why is there a URL restriction?

Comment: OK, I don't mind the URL changing but I want to keep the design the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would embedding the third-party payment page in a DIV or IFRAME element inside your application page suit you? Possibly using a [modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to contain it?

It wouldn't give you complete control over the layout, but your headers, footers, navigation bars, etc. would remain intact.

Note that, due to JavaScript sandboxing, JS code on your application page cannot interact with the 3rd-party page, and vice-versa.

Comment: Which payment page do you mean? Embed my payment/checkout page into the third-party page or as third-party page into my page?

Comment: Updated to make it clearer. I mean "Embed the 3rd party page inside your application's page."

Comment: Is this possible with all payment gateways?

Comment: I've no idea - I've never used a payment gateway! However, I've used this before for services which work in (what I believe is) a similar way to a payment gateway, so I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: OK, one final question, is it considered safe?

Comment: It's as safe as doing it in a new window, or whatever you were previously planning. If the URL you load into your IFRAME comes from a different domain (which, of course, it does), then javascript code on your application's page **CANNOT** interact with the DOM of the 3rd-party page, due to sandboxing.

Comment: It is safe, but the problem is the user can't see if it's a secure connection to the payment gateway, since it's in an iframe. So I would recommend to go direct to the payment gateway. There are gateways where you can adjust the design...

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider when processing transactions on your site is that you will need to become a PCI Compliant vendor to handle credit card data. If credit card data touches your servers, your requirements can be very costly and time consuming endeavor.

There are many companies designed to handle the credit card processing off site while the customer remains on your site. This greatly reduces your PCI compliance scope.

Take a look at Recurly.js (js.recurly.com) or Stripe. Recurly is a great fit if you plan on handling recurring billing, Stripe for one-time transactions.

Disclaimer, I work for Recurly, so I'm biased, but also well-informed :) Give me a shout if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Customers can pay with credit cards while staying on your site if you have a transparent redirect in place. Some payment processors, such as Braintree, include this in their payment gateway. You can learn more about how transparent redirects work here: https://www.braintreepayments.com/tour/pci-compliance

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions out there, quite a few already mentioned in this thread.

Here is another in-app payment solution (i.e. in-app experience, keeps the customer on your page) from Google. It is particularly suitable for digital and virtual goods, subscriptions and micro-transactions.

https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial

https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/commerce/digital-goods/getting-started/